# Installing RHive : ant not building

Tags: r, linux, hadoop, ant, hive

I'm trying to install `RHive`, following [this tutorial](https://github.com/nexr/RHive). I'm doing exactly what is written, but I get an error when building `RHive` with `ant`. Here is what I'm doing :

```
$ sudo su fma
$ sudo apt-get install ant
$ cd /home/fma/downloads
$ sudo git clone https://github.com/nexr/RHive.git
$ cd RHive
$ ls

build.xml  ChangeLog  INSTALL  README.md  RHive  RHive.iml  rhive-logo.jpg  rhive-logo.png

$ export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive
$ export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
$ sudo ant build

Buildfile: /home/fma/downloads/RHive/build.xml

compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/fma/downloads/RHive/build/classes
    [javac] Compiling 21 source files to /home/fma/downloads/RHive/build/classes

BUILD FAILED
/home/fma/downloads/RHive/build.xml:39: /home/fma/downloads/RHive/${env.HADOOP_HOME} does not exist.

Total time: 1 second
```

I get that he's telling me that `$HADOOP_HOME` doesn't exit, but if I do `$ cd $HADOOP_HOME`, the prompt does change to tell me that I'm in `/usr/local/hadoop` (of course, that's where I installed Hadoop)

(Also, I don't know if it's relevant, but just in case : I also have

```
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
```

in my `~/.bashrc`)

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sooo... I went the brutal way.

```
$ sudo vim build.xml
```

In vim, went to the part with

```
<fileset dir="${env.HADOOP_HOME}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
<fileset dir="${env.HIVE_HOME}/lib/" includes="**/*.jar"/>
```

And replaced it with :

```
<fileset dir="/usr/local/hadoop" includes="**/*.jar"/>
<fileset dir="/usr/local/hive/lib/" includes="**/*.jar"/>
```

Saved with `:wq`, and then

```
$ sudo ant build
```

Got `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`. The building throws a lot of warnings, but I don't think it's because of my workaround, as the warnings are mostly about stuff being deprecated.